# Access a particular field in an array

Tags: plugins, php

How to extract only the image url from this array.

```
     <?php 
     
     $rec1= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fave_recommended-property-1', true);
     $rec2= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fave_recommended-property-2', true);
     $rec3= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fave_recommended-property-3', true);
     $rec4= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fave_recommended-property-4', true);
     $rec5= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fave_recommended-property-5', true);
     
     $rec1_vals = get_post_meta($rec1);
    
    echo $rec1_vals['fave_property_price'][0] . ' ' .  $rec1_vals['fave_property_price_postfix'][0]; echo '<br>';
    echo $rec1_vals['fave_property_bedrooms'][0] . ' BHK';
    
    $size = 'houzez-item-image-1';
    $properties_images = rwmb_meta( 'fave_property_images', 'type=plupload_image&size='.$size, $rec1_vals['fave_property_id'][0] );
```

In the Array $Property_images: I want only the Image url under [medium] to be displayed in html image. Each var $rec1... $rec5 has the same set to repeated. Unable to access only this part of the array. Please help is much appreciated..

The array output is huge I have pasted in short here...

```
Array
(
    [19991] => Array
        (
            [width] => 592
            [height] => 444
            [file] => 2021/07/1-88-scaled.jpg
            [sizes] => Array
                (
                    [medium] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => 1-88-300x211.jpg
                            [width] => 300
                            [height] => 211
                            [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                            [url] => https://doorsandshelters.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/1-88-300x211.jpg
                        )

                    [large] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => 1-88-1024x721.jpg
                            [width] => 1024
                            [height] => 721
                            [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                            [url] => https://doorsandshelters.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/1-88-1024x721.jpg
                        )

                    [thumbnail] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => 1-88-150x150.jpg
                            [width] => 150
                            [height] => 150
                            [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                            [url] => https://doorsandshelters.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/1-88-150x150.jpg
                        )

                    [medium_large] => Array
                        (
                            [file] => 1-88-768x540.jpg
                            [width] => 768
                            [height] => 540
                            [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                            [url] => https://doorsandshelters.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/1-88-768x540.jpg
                        )
```

Finally found the Answer. Thanks @Buttered_Toast!

```
 $rec1= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fave_recommended-property-1', true);
 $rec2= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fave_recommended-property-2', true);
 $rec3= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fave_recommended-property-3', true);
 $rec4= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fave_recommended-property-4', true);
 $rec5= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fave_recommended-property-5', true);
 
 $rec1_vals = get_post_meta($rec1);
 $rec2_vals = get_post_meta($rec2);
 $rec3_vals = get_post_meta($rec3);
 $rec4_vals = get_post_meta($rec4);
 $rec5_vals = get_post_meta($rec5);
 
 $size = 'houzez-item-image-1';

$properties_images_rec1 = rwmb_meta( 'fave_property_images', 'type=plupload_image&size='.$size, $rec1_vals['fave_property_id'][0] );
$properties_images_rec2 = rwmb_meta( 'fave_property_images', 'type=plupload_image&size='.$size, $rec2_vals['fave_property_id'][0] );
$properties_images_rec3 = rwmb_meta( 'fave_property_images', 'type=plupload_image&size='.$size, $rec3_vals['fave_property_id'][0] );
$properties_images_rec4 = rwmb_meta( 'fave_property_images', 'type=plupload_image&size='.$size, $rec4_vals['fave_property_id'][0] );
$properties_images_rec5 = rwmb_meta( 'fave_property_images', 'type=plupload_image&size='.$size, $rec5_vals['fave_property_id'][0] );
       

    get_images_medium_urls($medium_images_urls1, $properties_images_rec1);
    get_images_medium_urls($medium_images_urls2, $properties_images_rec2);
    get_images_medium_urls($medium_images_urls3, $properties_images_rec3);
    get_images_medium_urls($medium_images_urls4, $properties_images_rec4);
    get_images_medium_urls($medium_images_urls5, $properties_images_rec5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by your array you could do something like this.

This is the minimun code required to only get the medium size url

The function that handles finding all medium urls

```php
function get_images_medium_urls (&$urls = [], $arr, $find = ['medium', 'url']) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === $find[0]) $urls[] = $value[$find[1]];
        else if (is_array($value)) get_images_medium_urls($urls, $value, $find);
    }
}
```

Your variable is `$properties_images` so using the function will look like this

```php
get_images_medium_urls($medium_images_urls, $properties_images);
```

Ok now after you have called the function because the first argument we passed is `$medium_images_urls`, it will contain all found medium url like this

```php
Array
(
    [0] => https://doorsandshelters.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/1-88-300x211.jpg
)
```

If you would like in the future to get, for example, the urls of large images you can do this

```php
get_images_medium_urls($medium_images_urls, $properties_images, ['large', 'url']);
```

Yeah, the function name could be confusing if you use it to get anything other than medium images urls, but this is simply an example, change it however you want.

Comment: Oh thanks @Buttered_Tost that worked like a charm . But the $medium_images_urls[0] => has the image url of the current post. But i need it to fetch it for the custom type of post (property) by post id that I have entered..

Comment: @user3787062 I'm not sure I understand. `$medium_images_urls` contains all found medium urls, if you want to filter by other values as well le me know. Do you mean you want to get medium url of only `19991` id, for example?

Comment: Thanks for the help I just used the function and passed variables individually. I have updated my post please see it.